# can not share a folder between ubuntu 22.04 and windows 11,

Tags: networking, permissions, windows, samba

I am trying to share a folder between Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11.
The folder that I am trying to share is the public folder inside my home directory.

I can see that in Ubuntu the shared logo (the green share ) is on the folder, so I believe it is shared.

In Windows when I use \\192.168.0.139 (which is my Linux IP address), the Pubic folder appears, but when I am trying to access it, I am getting an error that I do not have permission to access the folder.

I used my Linux username and password, without any success.

How can I give access to my Ubuntu folder so I can access it from Windows and read/write to it create folders and delete files?

## Edit 1

When I look at the `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, I can not find any entry for sharing of the Public folder!

Comment: `/etc/smba/smb.conf` does not exist.  `/etc/samba/smb.conf` does.  You might want to go through https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#1-overview and learn how to setup a Samba share to be accessed.

Comment: A DuckDuckGo search for "windows 11 read linux partition" (without the quotes) returns several results.  I did something similar, but going the other way. I wanted to share a NTFS folder with Ubuntu.  I can post what I did  for you if you want to try that approach.

Comment: @Terrance Sorry it was a typing error, The file exist, but there is no entry related to public folder which I shared.

Comment: @Ken The ones that I found are explaining how to share a partition between a system with dual boot, but I am interested in accessing a folder on a different PC that runs Ubuntu from a Windows PC.

Comment: @Terrance I did what was documented in that web page but I am getting the error that I do not have access to the folder. I am using my Linux username and password in Windows to access the folder without any success.

Comment: I suspect you are missing the `usershare owner only = false` line in the smb.conf file that allows other users to access the files.

Comment: `usershare owner only` determines who can share a folder. By default it is set to yes meaning only I can share folders I own. If set to No / false it means any local user can share any folder owned by anybody. It has nothing to do with who can access the share.

Answer (score 0):

This answer has worked for me, but mind you that it is not at the user level logins, but more of a guest share allowing all on my network to connect to my share.

In your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file in the `[global]` section you probably need lines like below:

```
[global]
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    netbios name = intrepid
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    follow symlinks = yes
    wins support = true
    unix extensions = no
    client ntlmv2 auth = yes
    server role = standalone server
    os level = 20
    workgroup = home
    usershare owner only = false
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    guest ok = yes
    max log size = 1000
    ntlm auth = no
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    preferred master = yes
    printing = CUPS
    map to guest = bad user
    use sendfile = no
    usershare allow guests = yes
    acl allow execute always = true
    pam password change = yes
    unix password sync = yes
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    obey pam restrictions = yes
    dns proxy = no
    large readwrite = no
    local master = yes
    wide links = yes
    access based share enum = yes
```

Then when defining your share you will need something similar to below:

```
[BACKUP]
   path = "/home/terrance/Share"
   directory mask = 0775
   create mask = 0775
   browseable = yes
   writeable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   admin users = terrance
```

After it is all set, restart the Samba server.

```
sudo systemctl restart smbd.service
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I look at the /etc/samba/smb.conf, I can not find any entry for
> sharing of the Public folder!

Because you created the share within Files - your file manager. Those shares are listed someplace else.

Please verify that you created what samba calls a "usershare" of your Public folder with this command:

```
net usershare info --long
```

If you created this share allowing guest access it will not work not because of samba but because Ubuntu by default makes a user's home directory accessible only to that user.

A couple of workarounds:

Make the guest user look like you to samba by editing /etc/samba/smb.conf and right under the `workgroup = WORKGROUP` line add this one replacing mans with your Ubuntu login user name:

```
force user = mans
```

Then restart samba:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Or, you can access the public share from Windows with your own Ubuntu user name but you have to tell samba who that is. You do that with this command:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a mans
```